# Connect to a specific bluetooth paired device

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I've implemented a list with all of my paired devices, and now I'd like to know if it's possible to connect to some of them only with clicking on the item.

For example if my list contains a bluetooth device called X and I want to connect to it (with my app) click on it and the connection is stablished between device and my phone.

This is how I list my paired devices :

```
 myListView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.BTList);
    BTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    myListView.setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter);
    pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+ "\n" + device.getAddress());
```

Comment: This might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292441/android-switch-between-spp-bluetooth-devices/11358472#11358472

Comment: I need more details this answer is too much explained

Comment: if you success please post solution for connect to specific paired device.

Comment: @AjayPandya What do you mean?

Comment: I'm also looking for the scenario

Comment: You can use mac address of the device that you want to pair! @Skizo

Comment: Yes I can get macaddress but how can I connect to it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(java.util.UUID)   use your macadress to generate UUID

Comment: do you need libraly to connect via bluettoth?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the device you wish to pair to you can use an equals comparison.

```
private static final String DEVICE_WE_WANT_TO MATCH = "X";

String devName = device.getName();
if(devName.equals(DEVICE_WE_WANT_TO MATCH)){
    // Connect.
}
```

You can also use an app `UUID`

```
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
```

This will mean that only devices using this UUID will connect using your protocol, it's an extra layer of security for the app.

In this, latter, case, we're relying on one android device to be acting as a BT server and the other as a BT client.

Comment: I'm gonna test it, but I asked it to know how to connect, the list I allready showed up... but thanks anyways for the reply ;)

Comment: If you have time/and you want me to show how to connect programmatically, go ahead, your help is always welcome :D

Comment: Hi @Yvette Colomb, maybe you can help me out on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997669/android-acceleration-down-smash)? Big price on it :P