# Android SDK for printer fujitsu FTP-628WSL110

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

Recently I was asked to integrate with Printer: Fujitsu [FTP-628WSL110](https://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/MICRO/fcai/thermal-printers/ftp-628wsl110.pdf)

I really new to connecting printer over Bluetooth SPP but I'm too having a problem to find SDK for this printer.

Can someone guide me to achieve those tasks finding SDK, sending commands to it?

Any snippet or example or links are very appreciated.

Comment: Might help you [click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292441/android-switch-between-spp-bluetooth-devices)

Comment: thanks for your reply .. i managed to connecting it but commands to print images, next line , and similar is what i'm asking for.

But in all cases thank you for the link :)